# Struts2 performance issue

Tags: java, performance, struts2

I am using Struts2 in my application .it's working fine when there is less number of users.
But in real time there are around 3000 requests hiting to the application.And after some time my JVM get crashed.I checked the thread dump it seems to be lot of thread blocked while executing the OGNL expression.

And the CPu utilization is always around 130% in the pick times.Please suggest me what will be the best approach to run stuts2 application in highly scalable enviroment.

Comment: Can you expand on how you did the testing. What the results were exactly and perhaps if you have some strange OGNL expressions show them. If you are using a testing framework add that to this questions tag's because you'll get more expert testers in the audience.

Comment: What is the error when your JVM crashes?

Comment: @Steven :It get crashed due to memory outage in JVM,and cause of memory outage is due to lot of threads get blocked.

Comment: @Quaternion :This case happened in production so rolled back the application.We are doing the load testing in Jmeter.

Comment: VPS hosting due to memory limits can also cause crashes. How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 4):

- Let's see this, the default setting for `struts.ognl.enableExpressionCache`

> ### Caches parsed OGNL expressions, but can lead to memory leaks
>
> ### if the application generates a lot of different expressions
>
> struts.ognl.enableExpressionCache=true

- Or try optimize your Struts2 application by instructions in [Performance Tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/performance-tuning.html).
- Or monitoring your Struts2 application with [Java Melody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/), Struts2 action can be monitored by add an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Struuts2 you are using? there were some known issue with OGNL expression language.

follow this thread on struts2 mailing list it might help u [OGNL Discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@struts.apache.org/msg27930.html)

lately there has been a lot of performance improvement with OGNL so just specify the Struts2 version

Comment: struts2-core-2.2.1.jar ,ognl-3.0.jar